# Why find found, bind bound, fight fought, wind wound (i / ou) but cling clung, dig dug, spin spun, sting stung (i /u)?

Tags: past-tense

Why find found, bind bound, fight fought, wind wound (i / ou) but cling clung, dig dug, spin spun, sting stung (i /u)?

Comment: *spin, spun, **span*** - and (albeit less commonly) *sting, stung, **stang**...* Ain't English irregular verbs wonderful?

Comment: And *bring, brought*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It has span?

Comment: The obvious difference is that the first list is all long-i words, and the second all short-i.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: "it"? The full OED has several citations of Past Tense ***span*** under the verb ***spin***. Admittedly, the most recent is 1865, but personally I have no problem with [*It span out of control.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=span+out+of+control&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspan%20out%20of%20control%3B%2Cc0) I'm a *little* less comfortable with ***stang*** (also in OED), but although I probably wouldn't use it myself, I doubt I'd say anything to someone else who *did* use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, but in *look, looked, looked* the second form given is traditionally the past simple and the third, the past participle! This would give you *It sp**u**n out of control* and *It has often sp**a**n out of control*! But if you're saying *span* for the past tense and *spun* for the participle, then I definitely agree. That's definitely what I use, as a UKer!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I can be pretty lax about what forms I'll accept as "valid" (even if they're not the most *common* choice). But even I would balk at wearing *a shirt made of **span silk***. If I could afford it though, I wouldn't mind a [***spun silk shirt***](https://dege-skinner.co.uk/shop/product/shirts-and-ties/shirts/ivory-spun-silk-shirt/) (a snip at just £235! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Old English *ind*, *und* were lengthened to [aɪnd], [aʊnd]

The spelling “ou” is used in present-day English *found, bound, wound* to represent the diphthong vowel sound [aʊ]. Before the consonant cluster "nd", [aʊ] developed from Old English [u] (through a lengthened stage [uː]). But [aʊ] did not develop before “ng” or “nn” (the "n" in *spun* is a simplification of original "nn"). So Old English *und* generally became modern English “ound”, but Old English *ung* and *unn* did not become modern English “oung” or “ounn”.

Old English [i] was also lengthened and diphthongized to [aɪ] before “nd” (in *find, bind, wind* v.), but this is not associated with a spelling change.

#### Old English *h* affected the pronunciation of a preceding vowel

*Fight/fought* comes from an Old English verb containing *h*. Old English *h* also caused changes in the pronunciation of a preceding vowel. The development of vowels before *h* is too complicated for me to summarize, but in modern English spelling, "ugh" is not normally used by itself: instead, you'll see it only in combination with a preceding vowel letter as in "ough" or "augh". Likewise, "egh" does not generally occur: only "igh", "eigh" and "aigh".

#### *Dig/dug* has a different history

Verbs with “i” in the present and “(o)u” or “a” in the past or past participle generally go back to the Old English class 3 strong verbs.

The verbs from your list that were class 3 in Old English: *find, bind, wind, fight, cling, spin, sting.*

*Dig* does not go back to an Old English strong verb; its past tense form *dug* was created by analogy (according to the Oxford English Dictionary,
in the 16th century).